# Running AngularJS tests with Resharper

Tags: angularjs, resharper, typescript

I'm trying to implement an AngularJS application in Typescript using Visual Studio. The sample controller works, and now I'm trying to write and run some tests. When I create tests that are not related to Angular (for example, `1+1 == 2`), it runs fine. However, testing the controller functionality doesn't seem to work.

Here's my `tests.ts` file:

```
/// <reference path="../scripts/typings/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="../scripts/typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../scripts/typings/angularjs/angular-mocks.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../scripts/typings/angularjs/angular-scenario.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../app/scripts/controllers.ts"/>

'use strict';

describe("Unit controllers", () => {

    beforeEach(() => module("thisApp"));

    describe("Sample Controller", () => {

        var scope: ISampleScope;
        var ctrl;

        beforeEach(
            function() {
                inject(
                    function($rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService, $controller: ng.IControllerService) {
                        scope = <ISampleScope> $rootScope.$new();
                        ctrl = $controller('SampleCtrl', { $scope: scope });
                    }
                );
            });

        it("should have a message", () => {
            expect(element("#msg").text()).toBe("Hello");
        });

    });
})
```

When running this example, I have 3 errors:

```
ReferenceError: module is not defined
ReferenceError: inject is not defined
ReferenceError: element is not defined
```

I have added `*.d.js` files for all referenced files so that they are automatically added to the source, but it doesn't help.

My Jasmine version in R# settings is. Tried in all browsers and Phantom.JS - the result is identically unsuccessful.

Has anyone managed to get this working?

**EDIT**

Apparently, the issue is called by the fact that R# appends Jasmine dependencies **after** all your references. Then, `angular-mocks.js` checks for `window.jasmine` in attempt to register `window.module` and `window.inject` and fails.

I tried to pre-include my own version of Jasmine and a "bootloader" to make it initialize, which actually solved the problem with `module` and `inject` not being defined, but triggered a whole avalanche of errors deeper down there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out it's a bug in Resharper and it's already fixed:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-412388

Updating to 8.2.1 resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have included all of your reference comments, which will solve all of your type-checking and auto-completion requirements at design-time; you also need to remember to add all of the scripts at run-time, for example by including all your script tags in the web page in the right order.

You are likely to find that either

1. You are missing the `<script>` tag for Angular, or
2. You have placed it *after* your tests script

Comment: R# uses it's own HTML page for testing which I cannot modify. I used the trick with `.d.js` files being included when an eponymous `.d.ts` is being referenced, however it still didn't help. I updated the original issue with a little investigation result.